# Cant Load Content When Not In Main Game Class

Tags: c#, xna, loading, tile

```
public class Dirt : Tile
{
    Vector2 position;
    Texture2D texture;

    public Dirt(Game game, Vector2 Position)
        : base(game)
    {
        type = "dirt";
        textureName = "Textures/Dirt";

        position = Position;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        texture = Salvage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Dirt"); // This doesnt work

        base.LoadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (InputHandler.KeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            position.Y -= 1;
        }
        else if (InputHandler.KeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            position.Y += 1;
        }

        if (InputHandler.KeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            position.X += 1;
        }
        else if (InputHandler.KeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            position.X -= 1;
        }

        Camera.DesiredPosition = position;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Salvage.spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, Camera.Transformation);
        Salvage.spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        Salvage.spriteBatch.End();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

The loading seems to work fine if i load it in the Salvage class(Main game class)

Edit:

The error im getting is:

Salvage.spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture

Here is the code for Salvage class:

```
public class Salvage : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    public static GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public static ContentManager contentManager;
    public static SpriteFont spriteFont;
    public GameStateManager stateManager;
    public Rectangle ScreenRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    public Salvage()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = ScreenRectangle.Height;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = ScreenRectangle.Width;

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        contentManager = Content;

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/DefaultSpriteFont"); // This works fine

        stateManager = new GameStateManager(this);
        GameplayState gameplayState = new GameplayState(this, stateManager);

        Components.Add(new InputHandler(this));
        Components.Add(new Camera(this, ScreenRectangle));
        Components.Add(stateManager);

        stateManager.ChangeState(gameplayState);

    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || InputHandler.KeyReleased(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

And the code for Tile

```
public abstract class Tile : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent
{
    public string textureName;
    public string type;

    public Tile(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {

    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        base.LoadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here is the GamePlayState class

```
public class GameplayState : GameState
{

    public GameplayState(Game game, GameStateManager manager)
        : base(game, manager)
    {
        childGameComponents.Add(new Dirt(game, new Vector2(0, 0)));
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        base.LoadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. What error are you getting? Can you provide the relevant code for `Salvage` and `Tile` classes?

Comment: I think the bug is in the `GameState` class. Where does that come from?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen your problem.  You declare the `contentManager` variable, but you never assign it until the `LoadContent` method.  If you are loading `Dirt` before this, you won't have a valid `ContentManager` variable causing it to fail.

In your constructor of your `Salvage` class, add the following line:

`contentManager = Content;`

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I still get the same error, becuase i was not creating a Dirt Tile until the gameplayState class was made.

Comment: @DiddyKonga: Can you specify which class is instantiated first so I can get a better understanding of what it happening?

Comment: K well the chain pretty much goes like this, Salvage(Main Class) makes a GamePlayState then GamePlayState makes a Dirt Tile.